# MFSideMenu: UIScrollView doesn't show images

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, viewcontroller

I am using `MFSideMenu` in my app which have 4 `UIScrollViews` with the same code *I am using the same exact code in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)* in 4 different `UIViewControllers` which added as subviews whenever they're chosen form the `SideMenuViewController` and that is the code I am using to do that

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 1 //or any Index) {

    UIViewController *centerController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerController"];

    UIViewController *secondController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondController"];

    [centerController.view addSubview:secondController.view];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:centerController];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
} }
```

**The problem here is that the the view controllers don't show any images** *they show the UIScrollView background, though* **and when I test them separated** *in another application* **they work**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a few hours I didn't find the solution anywhere, but I managed to fix it myself.

The problem happened because I shouldn't have used `addSubView` and should have used my new view controller as a `UINavigationController` instead.

Like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (indexPath.row == 1 /*or any Index*/) {

   UIViewController *centerController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerController"];
   UIViewController *secondController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondController"];

   //Now we no longer need this-->[centerController.view addSubview:secondController.view];

   UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
   //Edit starts here
   NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:secondController];
   //Edit ends here
   navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
   [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed]; }
}
```